# php can't receive request from C# webrequest when post data length more than 8K

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to send base64 encoded data through C# `WebRequest` to php script. Then I receive sent data by `file_get_contents("php://input")`, when data length is lower than 8 KBs the php code is executed, otherwise it can't be executed. In the other hand php didn't receive the request.

the code C#:

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            // postData is Base64_encoded
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); 

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            responseData = SecurityUtils.DecryptUrlData(responseData);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return responseData;
```

Could any one help?

Comment: There are limits on how long a GET request can be, you're likely hitting those. Can you use POST?

Comment: Could you show your C# code that is performing the request?

Comment: Look at the web servers logs. If you can't find the request there, try setting up wireshark and see if you can find out if the request is actually coming through.

Answer (score 0):

The below is incorrect (mea culpa). You cannot use enctype=multipart/form-data with php://input. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Perhaps you can post your PHP code into your question as well?

---

Make sure that when you POST from the c# app to your PHP app that you set the enctype to multipart/form-data.

**Explanaition**

Are you using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data? There is a good explanation of the differenes here: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

According to the link above, posting data in the application/x-form-urlencoded format will put the body into the URL. Many servers and languages (PHP, Apache) will cut off or throw errors when the URL is greater than 8K. See SO question: [What is the maximum length for a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

Comment: i replaced "contentType" value to "multipart/form-data" but now file_get_contents("php://input") result is empty always, why?

Comment: i replaced 'contentType' value to 'multipart/form-data' but now     file_get_contents('php://input') result is empty always, why?
did it deference from application/x-www-form-urlencoded's output?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the content type for the request

   request.ContentType = "text/plain";
2. Check out php.ini´s [post_max_size](http://php.net/post-max-size) on the server side